# Emacs weirdness when trying to comment in Assembly

Tags: emacs, nasm

Suppose I have a block of code like so:

```
;;  outut
mov eax, 4          
mov ebx, 1          ; stdout
mov ecx, [ans]      ; move biggest element to accumulator
add ecx, 30h        ; convert to ascii representation
mov [buff], ecx     ; move to memory
mov ecx, buff       ; put pointer in ecx for printing
mov edx, 4          ; size, 4 bytes
int 80h             ; system call.
```

When I try to put a comment in the front to comment out a line:

```
;;  outut
;mov eax, 4          
mov ebx, 1          ; stdout
mov ecx, [ans]      ; move biggest element to accumulator
add ecx, 30h        ; convert to ascii representation
mov [buff], ecx     ; move to memory
mov ecx, buff       ; put pointer in ecx for printing
mov edx, 4          ; size, 4 bytes
int 80h             ; system call.
```

Instead of appearing there where I want it to go, it jumps to here:

```
;;  outut
mov eax, 4          ;
mov ebx, 1          ; stdout
mov ecx, [ans]      ; move biggest element to accumulator
add ecx, 30h        ; convert to ascii representation
mov [buff], ecx     ; move to memory
mov ecx, buff       ; put pointer in ecx for printing
mov edx, 4          ; size, 4 bytes
int 80h             ; system call.
```

And no matter what I do, I physically cannot comment out anything.

How can I fix this? It don't remember it always doing this, so i feel like I must have hit some combination of keys and it just happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`;` is bound to `asm-comment` in assembly mode.  You can either do a quoted insert with `C-q ;` on a case-by-case basis, or remove the binding and just use `M-;` (`comment-dwim`) for fancier commenting.  If you want to do the latter, set ";" locally to do a self-insert command:

```
(defun my-hook ()
  (local-set-key ";" 'self-insert-command))

(add-hook 'asm-mode-hook 'my-hook)
```

Comment: I do assembly nasm stuff on my school's server, so I don't think I'm able to define my own commands or am I able to do that?

Comment: You can either put the above code in your .emacs file, or else evaluate it in the *scratch* buffer.  If all else fails, when in your nasm buffer, hit `M-:` to call `eval-expression` and enter `(local-set-key ";" 'self-insert-command)`.

Comment: What's M-: ? Is that ALT + : ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  "M" refers to the "meta" key, which in practice is the "alt" key on normal (non-Mac) keyboards.